# simulating mouse click on the warcraft3 button using win api

Tags: c#, winapi

I wonder if it possible to get handle of any button of the warcraft 3 game? Tried to get it via spy++ and Control Viewer but there only main WC3 window is availible.
So any ideas or suggestions?

I'm trying to simulate click on the button. I think it is possible to do this using coordinates of the button, but i'm not sure if it possible to calculate such a coordinates for all the screen resolutions. If I mistaken somewhere - please, correct me!

Thanks everybody in advance!

***ADDITION***

WIN API

```
int x = 700;
int y = 70;
int lParam = ((x << 16) | (y & 0xffff));
int parentWindow = FindWindow("Warcraft III", "Warcraft III");
SendMessage(parentWindow, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, IntPtr.Zero, new IntPtr(lParam));
SendMessage(parentWindow, WM_LBUTTONUP, IntPtr.Zero, new IntPtr(lParam));
```

Such a code will press any button which is stayed active after I left Warcraft 3 window.

DIRECT INPUT

```
public void testMouse()
        {
            INPUT input_down = new INPUT();
            input_down.mi.dx = 700;
            input_down.mi.dy = 70;
            input_down.mi.mouseData = 0;
            input_down.mi.dwFlags = (int)MOUSEEVENTF.LEFTDOWN;

            INPUT input_up = input_down;
            input_up.mi.dwFlags = (int)MOUSEEVENTF.LEFTUP;

            INPUT[] input = { input_down, input_up };
            SendInput(2, input, Marshal.SizeOf(input_down));
        }
```

such a code do nothing at all.

Any help is greatly appreciated...

Comment: The Elf is on its way to level 80? :))))

Comment: he-he, nothing special, just going to conquer this miserable world ;)

Comment: Hi, sorry for being late. You asked this question 8 years ago :) Can you share your experience at this? I am trying to do the same and here is my question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65316317/jna-winapi-simulate-mouse-click-without-moving-the-cursor-doesnt-work-correc 
But nobody can help me with that. Could you please take a look and suggest me something?

Comment: Эх, просто проигнорировал мой коммент..

Comment: @Gepard hey mate, though I know I Russian I'll answer in English. Sorry for not responding for this long. Tbh I don't think I can help with this cause it was too long ago, I even lost the source code that happened to work in my case. All I can say is that it was working. Maybe the code snippet in the accepted answer can provide some kind of help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using spy++ I found out, that when we do an ordinary click, Warcraft get PostMessage() with MK_BUTTON as wParam. So to simulate mouse clicking in warcraft you need to send PostMessage() instead of SendMessage().

Here is the code:

```
        IntPtr parentWindow = (IntPtr)WinApi.FindWindow("Warcraft III", "Warcraft III");
        int X = 770;
        int Y = 127;
        Point temp = new Point(X, Y);
        IntPtr lParam = (IntPtr)((temp.Y << 16) | temp.X);
        IntPtr wParam = IntPtr.Zero;
        WinApi.PostMessage(parentWindow, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, (IntPtr)MK_LBUTTON, lParam);
        WinApi.PostMessage(parentWindow, WM_LBUTTONUP, wParam, lParam);
```

But problem with the button's universal coordinates for all screen resolutions is still remain.

Comment: Great. I would suggest you post a little code to show how you're doing this, and then feel free to accept your own answer if you think it is the best.

Answer (score 4):

I believe Warcraft III uses DirectX. So you should be looking for how to spoof DirectX input, not the Win32 API.

Related questions:

- [directx mouse click simulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/475860/directx-mouse-click-simulation)
- [Simulate mouse move in 3D games?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5302473/simulate-mouse-move-in-3d-games)

Comment: ohhh, tried to do some prototypes, but nothing worked. Please, see edition of the topic.

Comment: I've achieved the result I wanted, it seems that we can make coordinate-based emulation, not button one. Please, see my answer, if interested.