# How to send keys to a DirectX application with SendInput()?

Tags: c#, directx, sendinput

i need to send keys to a DirectX application.
i am trying to use SendInput() since it heard that it is the most lowest level of key simulating except DirectInput hook.

The problem is, it only works without any problems for Windows application but not for the DirectX application. i was searching for the solution and i found out that i have to use the Scancode instead of wVk and set the dwFlags to 0x0008 (scancode)

```
private static KEYBDINPUT createKeybdInput(ushort wVK, uint flag)
{
    KEYBDINPUT i = new KEYBDINPUT();

    i.wVk = 0;
    i.wScan = wVK;
    i.time = 0;
    i.dwExtraInfo = IntPtr.Zero;
    i.dwFlags = flag | (uint)0x0008;


    return i;
}


public void Keyboardpress()
{
    INPUT[] inp = new INPUT[2];

    inp[0].type = 1;
    inp[0].U.ki = createKeybdInput(0x41, 0x0000);
    inp[1].type = 1;
    inp[1].U.ki = createKeybdInput(0x41, 0x0002);



    if (SendInput(2, inp, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(INPUT))) == 0)
    {
        new Exception("Error: " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error().ToString());
    }

}
```

it should send "a" to the most foreground window, but my directX application dont react to that. I also tried to use the DirectX Scancodes (in my case for 'a' = 0x1E), still no changes.

however, it should work with SendInput(). i downloaded the software "Glovepie" to test if this program can simulate keys to the game. and it does so there is a way to do that and i dont think they hook into librarys. After some research it seems that they also use the SendInput() API. Do anyone know what i should do to make it work?

Thank you very much

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11637208/

Comment: I tried to use SPY++ to monitor the directx application but it didn't find any messages. it seems that the application use DirectInput. how can i send keys to a directx app with directinput? i heard that directinput only detect keypresses but dont simulate

Comment: EDIT: It seems to work with keybd_event for some reason

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you're sending the virtual key code for the character "a" (0x41) instead of the scan code (0x1E).

You specified in the dwFlags parameter that you wish to send scan codes. You can fix your code in two ways:

1: remove the "0x0008" bit from dwFlags, set wScan=0 and use wVk to send the virtual key code (0x41 in your example).

2: keep your code as it is but send 0x1E instead of 0x41 to send the scan code for "a" instead.

How to obtain the scan code from the virtual key code? Use the MapVirtualKey function. Using your example, MapVirtualKey(0x41,0) will return 0x1E as the scan code!